# Why I'm getting HTTPS Error BAD_REQUEST in Flutter

Tags: flutter, https, amazon-elb, http-status-code-400, dio

I am getting error 400 when using HTTPS. But it is reponding perfectly on HTTP request.
I'm using DIO 3.0.10 & Flutter 1.22.6, Server is AWSELB/2.0.
Here is the code,

```
    Dio http = Dio();
    String url = 'https://HOST:PORT/PATH?queries';
    
    try {
        Response response = await http.get(
            url,
            options: Options(headers: {
                HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token',
            })
        );

        if(response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok)
            return response.data;
        else
            throw NetworkException('Something went wrong with suggestion fetching');
    } on DioError catch(e) {
        throw NetworkException('Something went wrong with suggestion fetching.');
    }
```

I have also tried with POSTMAN & cURL, the API is working fine. But it is send 400 'Bad Request' error when sending with DIO. I have also tried other library http(0.13.0), in here also I'm getting 400 Bad Request.

I have tried DIO with Google Map API(HTTPS). In there I'm getting response perfectly fine. I'm not being able to find out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Does your server supports https?? If yes then can you show me your url where you are req... Generally this type of 400 error occurred in https when it is not configured properly

Comment: Yes, it supports HTTPS. URL => https://api.fitplush.com:20445